# Is it acceptable for answers to invoke religion?

Tags: discussion

[**This question**](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/40354/always-having-to-swallow-when-singing) seeks advice on becoming less nervous when performing in front of an audience. [**This answer**](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/65950/40842) essentially says that the issue is mental, and strengthening one's Christian faith can help one overcome one's nerves.

Is it acceptable to invoke a *specific* religion to answer a question? Speaking about religion from an "insider's" perspective feels like it might be a little close to evangelizing, which could become problematic for the site. On the other hand, research shows that prayer has psychological benefits. (This is not a religion-specific phenomenon and extends widely to many different religions.) So I feel like an answer along these lines might have been okay:

*Consider connecting more with your personal faith tradition, or finding a faith tradition to be a part of. Religious prayer, in virtually any form, has been shown to have beneficial psychological effects.*

Would this be an acceptable answer? Is any answer invoking religion acceptable, if the question is psychological in nature? Or is it okay as written because it's written from a personal perspective?

Answer (score 5):

That post actually appears to be a comment responding to a comment on another post, not an answer. So I have deleted it accordingly.

The existing post on using God's help is pretty low quality as it doesn't really say what or how to do this.

I think your suggestion would be more valuable, but could probably be expanded upon to help individuals work out how to use prayer as a relaxant.